# Read yaml file in java

Tags: java, yaml, cloud-foundry

I want to write java program to read set of data from YAML file in cloud foundry.

```
#Define CDN domains
---

    domains: 
     name : CDN1
     quality : 200..300
     cost : low
     location: http://

    name: CDN2
    quality: 400..500
    cost: high
    location: http://
```

Then, in the program based on the name and quality it should redirect the first request to new location.
Can anyone help me for this?
I`m entirely new in YAML! 
Based on my search, I can use snacked YAML or bean YAML, but I don't know what difference is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson to read YAML, which is widely supported in Spring: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml

Comment: Thank you. I can read YAML file with Jackson but now my question is how I can use if condition when I read data?

Comment: @Omid then that should be a separate new question on Stack Overflow